# CSS background:url Not working

Tags: html, css, web

The HTML code is

```css
<style>
.banner_image{

    padding-top: 75px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background: url(http://test.puurmondhygienist.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/slide_bg_2400x1080.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.banner_content{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 6%;
    padding-bottom: 6%;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-bottom: 12%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    max-width: 660px;
}
</style>
```

```html
             <div class="banner_image">
                    <div class="container">
                        <center>
                             <div class="banner_content">
                            
                                 <h1>We Sell Lifestyle</h1>
                                 <p>Flat 50% off on all brands</p>
                                 <a href="products.html"><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg active" value="Shop Now"></a> 
                            </div>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The image doesn't show up. Is there any issue with the CSS. I tried it many times, but that doesn't work. I even added the CSS file on the drive and tried it still it didnt worked, whats the issue? Please help.

Comment: It is working https://jsfiddle.net/vkjhnm43/

Comment: remove the style tags

Comment: Don't combined properties and Try to specify each property like this `background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; ...` see if that would work.

Comment: @Adam It looks cleaner especially if you have more than 200 classes ... By experience

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónR. yeah I know that, but it's worth a try to see if that would work. Iv'e had this problem in the past and for some reason it didn't work when adding ` no-repeat center center` but when I remove two and keep one then it would work

Comment: @Adam Thanks it worked! But why isn't it working with style tags?

Comment: To precise what @TemaniAfif means, snippets here behave like if the Javascript and CSS were loaded from external files. You don't put `<style>` tags in `.css` files or `<script>` tags in `.js` files. These tags are for the HTML section

Comment: @RaghavMaheshwari I really didn't find an answer for it, but it's strange. and as long it worked so I'm over it

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
background-image: url("http://test.puurmondhygienist.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/slide_bg_2400x1080.jpg");
```

I think it would work with background-image property. not only background. and I put quotations for URL. then I removed `no-repeat center center` and the end of code

Comment: Don't tell us down here. Revise your answer to make it complete.